# Why won't anything show up when I use VGA mode with the Digital Mars Compiler?

Tags: c, dos, vga

I'm trying to make my own game for DOSBox, and I'm having trouble writing to the VGA memory. I'm using Digital Mars Compiler, and I'm using the compilation flag -mmd.

Here's my code:

```
/*headers*/
#define VGA256 0x13
#define TEXT_MODE 0x03
#define SCREEN_RAM_START 0xA0000000L
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 320
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 200
#define SCREEN_SIZE 320 * 200

void set_mode(int mode)
{
    asm mov AH, 0;
    asm mov AL, mode;
    asm int 10h;
}

void set_pixel(int x, int y, char pixel_color)
{
    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)SCREEN_RAM_START;
    ptr[(y * SCREEN_HEIGHT) + x] = pixel_color;
}

int main()
{
    set_mode(VGA256);
    set_pixel(100, 150, 1);
    while (!kbhit()) {}
    set_mode(TEXT_MODE);
}
```

Comment: https://digitalmars.com/ctg/ctgMemoryModel.html

Answer (score 0):

I made the question for those struggling with VGA mode and the DMC when making games for DOSBOX.

The function `set_pixel` needs to be changed. The DM compiler uses far pointers and near pointers when compiling for 16-bit architecture. Also, it should be `y*SCREEN_WIDTH`.

New Version:

```
void set_pixel(int x, int y, char pixel_color)
{
    unsigned char __far *ptr = (unsigned char __far *)SCREEN_RAM_START;
    ptr[(y * SCREEN_WIDTH) + x] = pixel_color;
}
```